# Can anyone tell if the commit is done in gitbash in the following code?

Tags: git, commit, git-bash

This is my first commit in git. I got the following response :

---

```
*$ git commit -m "Initial commit 2"
[master 741933b] Initial commit 2
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 new.html*
```

---

Is the commit performed successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting started with Git can be daunting, especially if you're not used to the command line. A  few heuristics can help:

- If anything goes wrong, expect to see an error message clearly marked as such.
- If everything goes well, expect to see either nothing at all (a common part of the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy)) or a short confirmation message. That's what you're seeing in this case, reporting some details about what was actually saved as part of the commit.
- If unsure run `echo $?` as the immediately next command to see the exit code of the previous command. If it prints anything other than "0" the command *very likely* failed (some commands use non-zero exit codes to signal various non-error situations).

In this *specific* case you can use `git status` to show you the current status of the repository. You can tell that the commit was successful by the fact that there should be no "Changes to be committed" section in the output.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I started using gitbash and everything works fine.